# Installing 16.04 on iMac 17,1 5k

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

I can't for the life of me get this to boot.  I've successfully have the drive partitioned, and 16.04 installed correctly from USB stick. I had to set `acpi=off` and `nomodeset` to get the install to work.

But after the install, even with those same grub params, Ubuntu will not boot.  Just a blank purple window.  I've tried lots of variations, `1915.modeset=0`, `radeon.modeset=0`, etc.... but nothing.

Has anybody got Ubuntu installed on one of the new 5k imacs?  I've tried 14.04, 16.04, and Ubuntu 16.10.   It has to be something with the graphics system.  Not sure why it works fine during install, but not after install.

Comment: Have you try [this one](https://discussions.apple.com/message/29913372#message29913372)

Answer (score 0):

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a 5k imac without any issues with booting. To get sound to work (in particular the headphone jack) I had to add

options snd-hda-intel model=imac27_122

to the end of /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf